# PHP - explode supposed to return array but string given on array_shift

Tags: php, arrays, string, types

I have the following code:

```
$path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
$elements = explode('/', $path);
var_dump($elements);
echo is_array($elements) ? 'true' : 'false';
$elements=array_shift($elements);
```

`explode(delimeter, string)` should return `array`. And it is returning as `is_array(bool)` returns `true`, but `array_shift(array)` gives following error:

```
Warning
: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in
```

Why is this happening even when `$elements` is an array?

PHP 7.2.19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `array_shift()`-method shifts the first value of the array off and returns it. So if you run

```
$elements = array_shift($elements);
```

the contents of `$elements` will be the first element of the array (in your case a string).

You can use it like this:

```
$path = ltrim('/path/to/resource', '/');
$elements = explode('/', $path);
$first_element = array_shift($elements);
var_dump($first_element, $elements);
```

And the first element of the array will be in the variable `$first_element`. The `$elements`-array will no longer contain that element.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/DHcsJ

More info about the method can be found in the [official documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).